# Python Flask blocking other requests during POST of large file

Tags: python, rest, flask, blocking, werkzeug

I've got a component of a larger Flask RESTful API who's purpose is to take a very large file (several GB, specifically an OVA virtualization image file) as a POST body, and then save it to a block device directly (treated as just a normal file in my code).

The issue I'm having is twofold:

(1) During the upload, before the `save()` call is made, Flask is writing the file out to a temporary file. This is blocking, and during the time this save takes (up to many minutes for a very large file on a slower connection), the entire API is blocked; other requests to the API must wait for the upload to complete.

(2) I've tried working around this by deferring the initial save and using a custom `stream_factory` to `parse_form_data` which writes directly to the destination, instead of using the standard Flask RESTful parsing and then calling `save()`. This avoids writing to a temporary file (which in my case is a double-write and takes up a lot of temp space), but the blocking behaviour is the same, just happening a bit later in my code path.

Things I've tried:

1. I've tried both a standard `save()` as well as a custom `parse_form_data` as detailed above. No effect.
2. I've tried both the default Flask `run()` with `threaded=True` and without `threaded=True`. No effect.
3. I've tried both PyWSGI in addition to the default Flask `run()`. No effect.
4. With PyWSHI, I've tried both `monkey.patch_all()` and not. No effect.
5. I've tried using `os.set_blocking` to disable blocking with the custom `stream_factory` method. No effect.
6. I've tried running the `parse_form_data` in a thread, however since I must `join()` this to avoid the rest of the code proceeding until the upload is done, this also has no effect.

The relevant code can be found in [this particular commit to my project](https://github.com/parallelvirtualcluster/pvc/commit/ffaa4c033fee713f2f57a6bd89995a19302adda3) where I implemented the custom `stream_factory` workaround; note that I did this to try to stop the double-save, not to address this issue, but it shows the code paths around which I'm working.

This sort of has me stumped; I need to both support these large file uploads, but I cannot have the API block other requests while the upload happens. Is there any way to stop these large file uploads from blocking other requests to the API?

EDIT: I've found the solution is to just use the Flask "debug" server for my API. It works properly here with `threading=True` and no moneypatch business, while Gevent/PyWSGI doesn't, and in my usecase the "debug" server is more than functional enough. Consider this closed without coming up with an explanation or "proper" solution.

Comment: Try asking here as well https://discord.com/channels/531221516914917387/531221866145251366

Comment: and also look at this? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/

Comment: Celery would only really help once the file is on the remote side; it's getting it there that's the issue.

Comment: Owh well. Thought it would.. my bad.. this is definitely above my pay grade

Comment: That's OK thanks anyways! Most of the similar resources I've come across tend to talk about relatively small files, from a few kB to a few MB, but since I'm dealing with GB-sized files, this blocking becomes a major issue for my software, and there's little in the way of references for such implementations.

Comment: Why don't you use Flask with Gunicorn? And add enough workers?

Comment: For what I'm doing, Gunicorn does somewhat make sense but would require me refactoring a lot to move away from a single-binary setup, and ultimately the API isn't designed for web-scale traffic, just system administration; it's just bad for my system to be completely unresponsive for several minutes at a time while uploading  a file, while someone else might want to view some system stats or something. That's probably ideal long term, but I'm also hoping to understand exactly why PyWSGI/Gevent is doing this, since it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @J.G. I was using Guicorn and seeing the error above if trying to make a request while another request was blocking. This helped me thanks! Just added `--workers=3` to the command